# cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit ERC721: transfer of token that is not own

Tags: solidity, erc-721

I'm getting ERC721 transfer of token that is not own error when trying to buy a token, I don't want to store the token in the marketplace SM and it should be stored in the seller wallet. any help, please?

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"code":-32603,"message":"execution reverted: ERC721: transfer of token that is not own","data":{"originalError":{"code":3,"data":"0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000294552433732313a207472616e73666572206f6620746f6b656e2074686174206973206e6f74206f776e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","message":"execution reverted: ERC721: transfer of token that is not own"}}}, method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xFeB43BA464258c453D7aA678210fD49zxnFRgfBN","to":"0x81b6BfD84f5FBa7c737382Bd535875DDF4bFD443","value":
```

Creat ERC721 Token:

```
function createToken(string memory _tokenURI) public returns (uint) {
    _tokenIds.increment();
    uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();

    _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, _tokenURI);
    setApprovalForAll(contractAddress, true);
    return newItemId;}
```

Put on Sale and transfer:

```
function createSale( 
        address nftContract,
        uint256 itemId
    ) public payable nonReentrant {
    uint price = idToMarketItem[itemId].price;
    uint tokenId = idToMarketItem[itemId].tokenId;
    require(msg.value == price, "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the 
    purchase");

    idToMarketItem[itemId].seller.transfer(msg.value);
    IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(owner, msg.sender, tokenId);
    idToMarketItem[itemId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
    idToMarketItem[itemId].sold = true;
    _itemsSold.increment();
    payable(owner).transfer(listingPrice); 
}
```

Comment: From the error message it looks like the market isn't approved to transfer the tokens. I'd check the approve details.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error you will see

> ERC721: transfer of token that is not own"

Which is I think returned by a require() function. You can check it's condition but as the messages says, you are trying to transfer a token but you don't have that token.

Comment: Yes I shouldn't store the token in the marketplace and it should be stored in the seller wallet that is why I implemented the setApprovalForAll() but it seems I'm missing something:(

Comment: Honestly, I didn't understand what you are trying to do